# How can I stop setInterval

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval, clearinterval

I am making canvas creation by for loop.
Each 20 circles wihch has each different size shows up every second.
I need to stop/escape loop when the total of circles becomes 100.

I tried to stop interval like below. However, it continues looping in console even though the shape of circle stops showing up.

```
if (circles.length > 100) {
  console.log('STOP');
  return;
}
```

Is there any way?

Thank you.

```js
class circle {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.r = 0;
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let colors = ["#96ceb4","#ffeead","#ff6f69","#ffcc5c","#88d8b0"];
let circles = new Array();

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

  function draw() {
    for (let i=0; i < 20; i++) { //20 blocks at a time
      const  item = new circle();

      item.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
      item.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
      item.r = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);

      circles.push(item);
      console.log(circles.length);
      if (circles.length > 100) {
        console.log('STOP');
        return;
      }

      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
      context.globalAlpha=0.5;
      context.arc(item.x, item.y, item.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      context.fill();

    };
  };
  setInterval(draw, 1000);

});
```

```css
body {overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Check out this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval . `setInterval()` returns an id that you cna pass to  `clearInterval()` to stop your loop I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I knew I needed `clearInterval` but didn't know how. Now, solved the problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the setInterval return to get the id to clear.

```js
class circle {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.r = 0;
  }
}

var timer;

function stopTimer(){
clearInterval(timer);
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let colors = ["#96ceb4","#ffeead","#ff6f69","#ffcc5c","#88d8b0"];
let circles = new Array();

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  context.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );

  function draw() {
    for (let i=0; i < 20; i++) { //20 blocks at a time
      const  item = new circle();

      item.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
      item.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
      item.r = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);

      circles.push(item);
      console.log(circles.length);
      if (circles.length > 100) {
        console.log('STOP');
        stopTimer();
        return;
      }

      context.beginPath();
      context.fillStyle=colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
      context.globalAlpha=0.5;
      context.arc(item.x, item.y, item.r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
      context.fill();

    };
  };
  timer = setInterval(draw, 1000);

});
```

```css
body {overflow: hidden;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Also note that if you're using this to make an animation it's better to use `requestAnimationFrame`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I knew I needed to use clearInterval but didn't know how. Also, thanks for your advise. I'll try `requestAnimationFrame`.